# Private key could not be loaded when I run "knife client list"

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, installation, knife

Configuration file written to /home/ubuntu/sudo /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb

```
ubuntu@mychefclient:~$ knife client list
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem
Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable
```

Comment: paste your `knife.rb` to troubleshoot further.

Comment: log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'ubuntu_client'
client_key               '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/ubuntu_client.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://mychefserver.example.com:443'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/home/ubuntu/chefrepo/.chef/syntax_check_cache'

Comment: what is the output of command `file /etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem` ?

Comment: You are executing the `knife client list` in `~`. Try it in `~/chef-repo/`, otherwise it wouldn't pick up your `.chef/knife.rb` file

Comment: "WARNING: No knife configuration file found".... That's the first clue!. Try "knife client list -c /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb"

Comment: you need the knife configuration at `/home/ubuntu/.chef/knife.rb`, or specify one by parameter `-c <path-to-your-knife.rb>`. Plus, you need private key of your knife client with admin privilege.

Comment: I am facing the same issue .when I run knife client list WARNING: No knife configuration file found ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable How ever I have defined the path in the bash_profile also and have the knife.rb file in the /root/chef-repo/.chef. Please help me

Comment: @StephenKing: I have even set the environmental varibale in bash.profile as `# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PATH="/opt/chef/embedded/bin/:$PATH"`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please check once that the knife.rb file is there in .chef/knife.rb.

If not run the following command:

```
knife configure initial
```

so it will create knife.rb, then check the path of client key in knife.rb and cross check whether the client.pem is present on that location.

If this doesn't work.

just go to the client node and delete client.pem from /etc/chef, then run chef-client so it will create client.pem again. Now copy that client.pem on to the server and add that location into the knife.rb

It will work definitely :)

Comment: The documentation of all this is horrible, thanks for this answer, worked fine!

Comment: I'm running this command but it doesn't generate the client.pem file--even after deleting the `.chef` folder and regenerating.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jyoti and Alan's answer, you might also wanna try and create a user from the webui of chef from your browser.

Read the location of the client.pem from knife.rb. 
Now go to your browser and create a new user as admin and copy the private key. Remember the private key will not be shown again, so be alert on that front.

Create a file at that location and copy the contents.

Worked for me, hope it works for you.

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running knife command from .chef folder helped

Comment: You probably configured it with a relative path and hence the issue, try configuring it with an absolute path and you'll be able to run the knife commands from anywhere